# ffmpeg - Overlay one video on to another

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to overlay one video on to another.I have two videos with same time duration.

Aim is to make upper video little transparent so that one can see whats happening in background video.

I've tried below **command** :

```
String command="ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/two.mp4 -i /sdcard/videokit/inone.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=100:100:eof_action=pass[v] -map [v] /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4";
```

In this command upper video isn't matching(In context of height and width) with video at back.

**Confusion :**  There may be a possibility that background video wont have same height width as upper video cause it comes dynamically in that case how should I manage..!!!

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want both videos to have the same dimensions? If yes, which one do you wish to resize?

Comment: @Mulvya Yes and video will come dynamically by capturing or from gallery  that's where i am confused how can manage it and how should i give dimensions to make it proper!! , the app will be for tablet and mobile, Is it appropriate to use fix dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

The command below resizes the upper video to match the base video and also gives it transparency.

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/two.mp4 -i /sdcard/videokit/inone.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" -map [v] /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4
```

The `scale2ref` resizes the second video to match the dimensions of the first. Then the `colorchannelmixer` tweaks the alpha channel to give it 50% transparency.

Comment: It crashed, [Error](http://pastebin.com/Ymi8Fjd6)

Comment: Seems like a resource issue. - "*The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.*"

Comment: I always get this error when I hit wrong command

Comment: Need to see ffmpeg's log.

Comment: How can i get that? I am running as an android project

Comment: Add `-report` to the command. A log file will be made.

Comment: you mean at the end of command! right? I am not getting anything

Comment: @Nisarg `-report` is a "global option", so it should be the first option. However, it will probably still work even if used as a trailing option. Look for a file named something like `ffmpeg-20160922-081554.log`.

Comment: Yeah, I regularly use it as a trailing option.

Comment: @Mulvya I cant generate any log file, it still gives same error..!!

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -report` and search for `ffmpeg*.log` files

Comment: @Mulvya i tried with *String newCommand="ffmpeg -report -y -i /sdcard/videokit/intwo.mp4 -i /sdcard/videokit/inone.mp4 -filter_complex [1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay=eof_action=pass[v] -map [v] /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4";* , still gives that error.

Comment: Just `ffmpeg -report`

Comment: @Mulvya I got [this](http://pastebin.com/x7FTZH4C) error.

Comment: There's some license error.

Comment: @Mulvya I always get that error even if its working command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45792/discussion-between-nisarg-and-mulvya).